# could not get gem5 running

Tags: gem

kept having this message on my command console

```
"scons: *** No SConstruct file found.
File "/usr/local/lib/scons-2.4.1/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 923, in _main"
```

when i type this command `scons build/ARM/gem5.opt` on my ubuntu os.

Comment: Any luck with the issue?

Comment: Here is an automated Ubuntu 18.04 Docker setup: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/d6d7f15c912ed6371c8cf15a93f43488d6fc5efb#docker If you reach further problems, please provide your exact gem5 git commit, and your OS version, and consider asking under the gem5 tag in Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gem5

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Python version:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-construct
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python-construct
```

Or using `pip`

```
sudo pip install construct
```